# Windows 10 Two Wifi Adapters. Can I force a specific adapter to connect AUTOMATICALLY to a specified Access Point

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, wireless-access-point

In windows 10 I can choose to connect automatically to an AP.

I have a local wireless LAN for printers, and another router connected to the Internet.

I purchased an extra Wifi dongle to connect to the printer LAN.

My aim:
WiFi card 1 (Internal) should connect automatically to Internet Router
WiFI adapter 2 (USB) should connect automatically to printers LAN *when inserted*.

Is there a way in windows 10 to force a specific network adapter connect to a specified AP

Comment: I have not seen any native way to have a USB card (I have a USB Internet stick) associate with a different app than the main connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My aim: WiFi card 1 (Internal) should connect automatically to
> Internet Router WiFI adapter 2 (USB) should connect automatically to
> printers LAN when inserted.

If you look in the advanced properties of TCP/IP, the metric chooses the active adapter and uses that to attach the adapter to TCP/IP.

So therefore, there is not any native way to have a USB card (I have a USB Internet stick) associate with a different app than the main connection.

It is often necessary to disconnect from one Adapter (say LAN) and connect to USB source. I have to do this.

That is really under the control of Windows and the Metric / connection setup. The user would have to manage this manually.

In my own work, I keep Printers on the main LAN for simple and easy access.